# Determining under what conditions an exponential function is linear

Tags: linear, approximation

I'm working through an exercise to determine when an exponential function of the form:

```
y = ae^(bx)+c
```

is approximately or exactly linear (of the form `y=mx+d`)

Surely it takes the form `y=mx+d` when `e^(bx)` equals `x`, which solves to `b=log(x)/x`. But that doesn't lead me anywhere given that `b` is a constant and `log(x)/x` is not.

I've also tried to solve the equation: `ae^(bx)+c = mx+d`, which led me as far as `bx-log(x) = (a/m)(d-c+1)`. I was hoping this would give me an understanding of the problem, but I'm stuck there.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to formulate a set of parameters `a, b, and c` that lead to the function taking a linear form. Or, to demonstrate mathematically that this is or isn't possible. Thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to define "close to" for your purposes. You could look at the behavior of ln(x)/x, and focus your attention between say x=2 and x=4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Exponential functions $x\to e^{bx}$ are not linear.

When $a=0$ or $b=0$ the function $x \to a e^{bx} + c$ is constant, which is linear.  To handle the remaining possibilities, assume that $a\ne0$ and $b\ne 0.$  Let's find $(a,b)$ for which this function is linear.  When it is, so is the function $h: x\to e^{bx}.$  However, *the latter is not linear on any set of three or more points.*

To see why not, let $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3$ be three distinct points in the domain.  Because $h$ is strictly convex (proof: its second derivative $b^2 e^{bx}$ is strictly positive everywhere), the value of $h$ at the middle point $x_2$ cannot equal the value of the linear function determined by the endpoints $(x_1,h(x_1))$ and $(x_3,h(x_3)),$ whence $h$ is not linear.

Incidentally, all functions defined on sets of just one or two (real) numbers are linear.  The real import of the foregoing is that *no function expressible as $x\to e^{bx}$ is linear even on very tiny intervals.*  That follows from the foregoing because even tiny intervals contain more than two points.

---

#### 2. One can approximate exponentials by linear functions.

The interesting aspect of the question concerns how to *approximate* $y:\,x\to ae^{bx}+c$ by some linear function $x\to mx + d.$   A standard way is through Ordinary Least Squares regression.  Given a probability distribution $F_X$ for $x,$ this method finds numbers $(d,m)$ to minimize the mean squared difference between the values of the function and its approximator; namely,

$$\eqalign{
\text{Mean squared difference}(d,m) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |y(x) - (mx+d)|^2 \mathrm{d}F_X(x) \\ &= E[(ae^{bX}+c - (mX+d))^2]}\tag{*}$$

where $X$ is any random variable with distribution $F_X.$

As is well known--and constantly referred to on the pages of this site--there is a  solution $(\hat d, \hat m)$ given by the Normal equations and it can be expressed in matrix form as

$$\pmatrix{\hat d \\ \hat m} = \pmatrix{1 & E[X] \\ E[X] & E[X^2]}^{-1} \pmatrix{E[y(X)] \\ E[Xy(X)]}\tag{**}$$

In particular, when it makes sense to change the units of measurement of $X,$ you can standardize it (through a suitable shift and rescaling) to put its mean $E(X)$ at $0$ and establish a unit variance, whence $E(X^2)=1$ and the matrix in $(**)$ becomes the identity; whence, *for standardized variables $X,$*

$$\pmatrix{\hat d \\ \hat m} = \pmatrix{E[y(X)] \\ E[Xy(X)]}.$$

This reveals $\hat d$ (the intercept) as the mean of the random variable $y(X)$ and $\hat m$ (the slope) as the *covariance* of $(X,y(X)).$

For example, let $X$ have a standard Normal distribution.  To work out the OLS fit to $ae^{bX}+c,$ compute

$$E[X] = 0,\quad E[X^2] = 1,\quad E[ae^{bX}+c] = ae^{b^2/2}+c,\quad E[X(ae^{bX}+c)]= abe^{b^2/2}$$

giving

$$\pmatrix{\hat d \\ \hat m} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}^{-1} \pmatrix{ ae^{b^2/2}+c \\ abe^{b^2/2}} = \pmatrix{ ae^{b^2/2}+c \\ abe^{b^2/2}}.$$

Thus, the best linear approximator is the function

$$x \to \hat d + \hat{m} x = ae^{b^2/2}\left(c + bx\right).\tag{***}$$

[image: Figure]

*In this figure, the $x$ coordinates have a Normal distribution with mean $\mu=0$ and standard deviation $\sigma=1.$ The red curve graphs the function $x\to ae^{bx}+c$ with $a=1/2,$ $b=-1/2,$ and $c=1.$  The blue line is the OLS fit $(\text{***}).$*

Because a Normal distribution focuses much of its probability between $\mu-\sigma$ and $\mu+\sigma,$ the OLS solution makes the line come relatively close to the curve in this region, as is apparent in the figure.  The OLS objective $(*)$ is the *weighted $L^2$ distance* between these curves: it heavily penalizes large (vertical) differences compared to small distances and it weights all those differences according to the distribution of $X.$  Thus, it "cares" relatively little about the larger discrepancies more than a few standard deviations away from the mean.

---

**There are, of course, other methods to approximate a function $y$ by a linear function,** depending on how you measure the discrepancy between the function and its approximator and depending on what probability distribution you assume for its argument $x.$  The OLS method is particularly simple and tractable, so even when your underlying statistical problem requires a different measure of discrepancy (such as maximum deviation), the OLS solution may serve as a good starting point to search for a solution.

**Finally, lest elements of this analysis seem unusual,** note that when you have a *dataset* of the form $(x_1,y(x_1)), (x_2,y(x_2)), \ldots, (x_n, y(x_n))$ for some function $y,$ you may view it as the function $y$ weighted by the empirical distribution of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n).$ This distribution is discrete, so the expectations in $(*)$ and $(**)$ become summations, which you will recognize as the standard way to express the Normal equations.

Comment: Great answer (+1), but perhaps consider modifying the title of the first section, to be consistent with your first sentence.  Maybe something like, "Exponentials are not linear (unless they are constant)".

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the suggestion.   I will emphasize that in the title as you suggest.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for putting in the effort to do this. Phenomenal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've basically almost answered the question already. If the function is **exactly** linear when `b=log(x)/x`, then it will be **approximately** linear when `b` is close enough to `log(x)/x`. So if you set a cut-off value for how different `b` is allowed to be from `log(x)/x`, then that does it.

If `b` is known then your function will be "approximately" linear for those values of `x` that bring `log(x)/x` close enough to `b` (depending on how you define your cut-off).

Comment: But b is a constant and log(x)/x is not. For instance, if my x-values are 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, and 12, how could I possibly say that b must be near x/log(x), which is obviously multiple values.